# How can I add a name for an existing conda environment on Linux?

Tags: linux, anaconda, conda, environment

I just started using conda to install packages two months ago. At that moment, following instruction online, I silly created individual environment for each package. I have to switch between environments. I did not give a name for each environment, so I have to input whole path. I am wondering how to add a name for an existing environment?

If I run "conda env list", I could get below output which is saved in ~/.conda/environments.txt

```
base                  *  /cm/shared/apps/anaconda2
py27                     /cm/shared/apps/anaconda2/envs/py27
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/envs/gsas2_env
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/envs/pmg_env
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/envs/py3.8
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/envs/r_env
                         /cm/shared/apps/anaconda3/envs/scipy_env
```

I hope to create a name for each environment, just like "py27" is for "/cm/shared/apps/anaconda2/envs/py27".

I highly appreciate it if you could directly merge all environments into one.

Thanks for your help.

BTW: I created these environments using the root account, and then copy the path to regular user account "~/.conda/environments.txt"

Comment: Do you actually have both Anaconda 2 and 3 installed? or did you manually create that `anaconda3/envs` folder for putting Python 3 environments in?

Comment: You cannot copy conda environments in the file system and expect things to work. Create a new environment with the name you want, with the user you want, then just re-install the packages you need in there. Then delete all the unnamed environments. And please get rid of Python 2.7, its End of Life is in two weeks.

Comment: @merv. Thanks for your questions. Yes. I have both Anaconda 2 and 3 installed. When I created environments, like pmg_env, conda added these environments in anaconda3/envs. I gradually learned where the environments are and copy the path to ~/.conda/environments.txt. So I can use "conda env list" to check those environments.

Comment: @Roland Weber, thanks for your suggestion.